# How to calculate the triple integral $\iiint_{\Omega_t}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$\iiint_{\Omega_t}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32}$, where $\Omega_t$ is the ellipsoid and $\Omega_t=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq 1$

I want to use the change variable for $u=\frac xa, v=\frac yb,w=\frac zc$, but after this, then we may have a complicated form for inside thing.
How can I do for this integral. Should I think about the Gauss Theorem?

Comment: Here is double edge sword: or you simplify integrand or limits of integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Do the substitution $$(x,y,z)=(ar\sin(\theta )\cos(\varphi ),br\sin(\theta )\sin(\varphi ),cr\cos \theta ),$$

where $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ and $\varphi \in (0,2\pi)$ and $r\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y = br \sin (\theta) \sin (\varphi)$?

Comment: @sudeep5221: You are absolutely right. Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Yes, and what a lovely integrand you have to contend with.

Comment: Thanks, is it the general sphere coordinates? It makes the same sense if I change variable first then make them in to sphere coordinates. For the inside integral, it is still very hard to do. Is there the only way to do this?